# dual NICs linux

Tags: linux, lan

my `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` is

```
255 local
254 main
253 default
0   unspec
1 brain
2 strom
```

I'm using below given `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        hwaddress ether 00:10:5a:02:2b:0e
        address 192.168.1.149
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        up ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 table brain
        up ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 table brain
        up ip rule add from 192.168.1.149/32 table brain
        up ip rule add to 192.168.1.149/32 table brain

allow-hotplug eth3
iface eth3 inet static
        hwaddress ether 00:15:17:95:61:eb
        address 192.168.10.149
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.10.0
        broadcast 192.168.10.255
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        up ip route add 192.168.10.0/24 dev eth3 table strom
        up ip route add default via 192.168.10.1  dev eth3 table strom
        up ip rule add from 192.168.10.149/32 table strom
        up ip rule add to 192.168.10.149/32 table strom
```

for two uplinks for a linux machine -- with source policy routing

for `eth0`, things are fine -- I can ping yahoo.com using eth0, browsing is ok as well
     `#ping -I eth0 yahoo.com`
works fine. I can also browse internet on `eth0.`

now the `eth3`
when I do a `ping` using `eth3`, I dont get a response either

```
ping -I eth3 yahoo.com
PING yahoo.com (72.30.35.10) from 192.168.10.149 eth3: 56(84) bytes of data.
From strom (192.168.10.149) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From strom (192.168.10.149) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

but port 80 is working fine on `eth3` when I use `curl`

```
curl --interface eth3 http://checkip.amazonaws.com/
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ( this is a real IP of eth3 for outgoing, which means the traffic flown through eth3 )
```

when I ping using the gateway on `eth3`  I get response locally

```
#ping 192.168.10.1
PING 192.168.10.1 (192.168.10.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.10.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=5.53 ms
```

only the ping outside the LAN for `eth3` is not working --

Samba Shares on the eth3 LAN side is also working fine

now the tcpdump  of ping on `eth3`

```
tcpdump -i eth3
```

I see only `who-has`

```
14:18:07.747843 ARP, Request who-has 72.30.35.10 tell 192.168.10.149, length 28
14:18:08.745739 ARP, Request who-has 72.30.35.10 tell 192.168.10.149, length 28
14:18:09.745736 ARP, Request who-has 72.30.35.10 tell 192.168.10.149, length 28
14:18:10.763054 ARP, Request who-has 72.30.35.10 tell 192.168.10.149, length 28
14:18:11.761736 ARP, Request who-has 72.30.35.10 tell 192.168.10.149, length 28
```

I get a simple no understanding why the ping is not working for the outgoing internet world for `eth3`

my routing table is

```
# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth3
```

my policy routing is

```
# ip route show table strom
default via 192.168.10.1 dev eth3
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth3  scope link


#ip route show table brain
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  scope link

#ip rule show
0:      from all lookup local
32762:  from all to 192.168.1.149 lookup brain
32763:  from all to 192.168.10.149 lookup strom
32764:  from 192.168.1.149 lookup brain
32765:  from 192.168.10.149 lookup strom
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

/etc/hosts entry for both LANs

```
192.168.1.149   puppy
192.168.10.149  strom
```